# Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network during our review

Tags: ios, ipv6, crash-reports

```
{"app_name":"vegecart","timestamp":"2018-03-14 18:23:03.00 -0700","app_version":"16.0","slice_uuid":"85dc3cef-370e-3818-9eab-976c8850e675","adam_id":0,"build_version":"16","bundleID":"com.kw4s.vegecart","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)","incident_id":"D6497F75-8811-4756-B897-A5D99D0EE2B1","name":"vegecart"}

Incident Identifier: D6497F75-8811-4756-B897-A5D99D0EE2B1
CrashReporter Key:   f5c30c62cf19fb8308fe7f011f232669cb001d70
Hardware Model:      iPad5,1
Device Model:        J96AP
Process:             vegecart [1212]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/65FF609A-2BDE-418D-9488-EB172D1C5A92/vegecart.app/vegecart
Identifier:          com.kw4s.vegecart
Version:             16 (16.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd.development [1]
Coalition:           com.kw4s.vegecart [579]


Date/Time:           2018-03-14 18:23:02.7751 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-03-14 18:21:57.7328 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)
Baseband Version:    n/a
UDID:                9c3b26e45a84cce589ac15536839641df5a44f07
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100940260
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:

Timestamp               Thread     Type        Activity             PID
2018-03-14 18:21:58.6471 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 AssertionServices: BKSWorkspace created.
2018-03-14 18:21:58.8527 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 AccessibilitySettingsLoader: Loading settings loader: (system: 0)
2018-03-14 18:21:58.8575 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 AccessibilitySettingsLoader: AXSettingsLoader told to start
2018-03-14 18:21:58.8720 -0700  0x5b17 1024 0x0 1212 FrontBoardServices: [FBSScene] [com.kw4s.vegecart] Created client agent: 
2018-03-14 18:21:59.1699 -0700  0x5b1a 1024 0x0 1212 libsystem_network.dylib: -[NWConcrete_nw_connection initWithEndpoint:parameters:] @ endpoint: [www.vegecart.com:443] parameters: [stream, pid: 1212, sanitized url: https://www.vegecart.com/api/v1/flag, tls]
2018-03-14 18:21:59.1708 -0700  0x5b1a 1024 0x0 1212 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 www.vegecart.com:443 initial path (null)]
2018-03-14 18:21:59.1709 -0700  0x5b1a 1024 0x0 1212 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 www.vegecart.com:443 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2018-03-14 18:21:59.1720 -0700  0x5b1a 1024 0x0 1212 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 www.vegecart.com:443 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2018-03-14 18:21:59.1721 -0700  0x5b1a 1024 0x0 1212 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 www.vegecart.com:443 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2018-03-14 18:21:59.1742 -0700  0x5b1a 1024 0x0 1212 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 www.vegecart.com:443 in_progress resolver (satisfied)] reported event resolver:start_dns
2018-03-14 18:21:59.1766 -0700  0x5b1a 1024 0x0 1212 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked Starting host resolution www.vegecart.com:443, flags 0x4000d000 proto 0
2018-03-14 18:21:59.1814 -0700  0x5b1a 1024 0x0 1212 libsystem_network.dylib: nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=www.vegecart.com. addr=::.0 ttl=60
2018-03-14 18:21:59.5005 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 HangTracer: refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 1
2018-03-14 18:21:59.5006 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 HangTracer: refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2018-03-14 18:21:59.5006 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 HangTracer: refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
2018-03-14 18:21:59.5008 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 HangTracer: BundleID: com.kw4s.vegecart saveTailspin: 0
2018-03-14 18:21:59.6124 -0700  0x5b19 1024 0x0 1212 BackBoardServices: xpc decoded handle=1212-1 for fence=8 via trace=3e00000003(62-3)
2018-03-14 18:21:59.6129 -0700  0x5b09 1024 0x0 1212 BackBoardServices: copied handle=1212-1 to handle=1212-2 for fence=8
2018-03-14 18:21:59.6133 -0700  0x5b09 1024 0x0 1212 BackBoardServices: released handle=1212-1 for fence=8
2018-03-14 18:21:59.6166 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 FrontBoardServices: now tracking trigger (1212:7a07:send_cp copy) from (1212:7a07:send_cp xpcCode) from (62:f333:send_cp copy) from (62:f333:send_cp copy) from (62:f333:send_cp copy) from (62:f333:send_cp copy) from (62:f333:send_cp xpcCode) from (68:7df1b:send_cp make) from (68:7df1b:receive init)
2018-03-14 18:21:59.6169 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 BackBoardServices: copied handle=1212-2 to handle=1212-3 for fence=8
2018-03-14 18:21:59.6172 -0700  0x5ad8 1024 0x0 1212 AssertionServices: Process lacks termination entitlement; not fetching initial set of termination assertions
```

Comment: you need to symbolicate the crash logs and see what the problem is. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding where your app crash then you add '[Crashlytics](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/overview.html)' in your project. Then this provides you with all information about the crash.

I am also confused when 2-time apple rejects my app then I add '[Crashlytics](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/overview.html)' in my project. Then I found where my  App cress with line no.