# Apple rejected the application due to crash on iOS 13.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, crash

My app was rejected because a crash on launch with iOS 13.3.1. I run it on real device but couldn't get any reason. Apple says it's a crash on iPad 13.3.1. I don't know how to address this problem. It's very hard to understand what's it is. I haven't got it before , following are the logs provided by Apple:

```
hread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a41b8efc 0x1a4193000 + 155388
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40d88b8 0x1a40d6000 + 10424
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a4068a74 0x1a3ff2000 + 486004
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a41803c8 0x1a417f000 + 5064
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a41805c0 0x1a417f000 + 5568
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a40e7308 0x1a40e1000 + 25352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a418d634 0x1a417f000 + 58932
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a418d5c0 0x1a417f000 + 58816
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4073fec 0x1a4071000 + 12268
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4076d1c 0x1a4071000 + 23836
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a9611254 0x1a95b7000 + 369236
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a9610f00 0x1a95b7000 + 368384
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a961146c 0x1a95b7000 + 369772
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a434a108 0x1a429c000 + 712968
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a434a05c 0x1a429c000 + 712796
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a43497c8 0x1a429c000 + 710600
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a4344694 0x1a429c000 + 689812
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a4343f40 0x1a429c000 + 687936
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001ae5d4534 0x1ae5d1000 + 13620
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a84cf580 0x1a7a8c000 + 10761600
20  Ebook Reader                    0x0000000100e6c278 0x100e18000 + 344696
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a41c2e18 0x1a41c2000 + 3608

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40df9e0 0x1a40d6000 + 39392

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40df9e0 0x1a40d6000 + 39392

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40df9e0 0x1a40d6000 + 39392

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40df9e0 0x1a40d6000 + 39392

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40df9e0 0x1a40d6000 + 39392

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40df9e0 0x1a40d6000 + 39392

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40df9e0 0x1a40d6000 + 39392

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a4196c04 0x1a4193000 + 15364
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a4196020 0x1a4193000 + 12320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a4349964 0x1a429c000 + 711012
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a43447fc 0x1a429c000 + 690172
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a4343f40 0x1a429c000 + 687936
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a4689340 0x1a4681000 + 33600
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a4689218 0x1a4681000 + 33304
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001a856ae9c 0x1a7a8c000 + 11398812
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a4687fa4 0x1a4681000 + 28580
9   Foundation                      0x00000001a47c3a74 0x1a4681000 + 1321588
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40d7840 0x1a40d6000 + 6208
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40df9f4 0x1a40d6000 + 39412


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a41b8efc 0x1a4193000 + 155388
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a40d88b8 0x1a40d6000 + 10424
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001a4068a74 0x1a3ff2000 + 486004
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a41803c8 0x1a417f000 + 5064
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a41805c0 0x1a417f000 + 5568
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a40e7308 0x1a40e1000 + 25352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a418d634 0x1a417f000 + 58932
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a418d5c0 0x1a417f000 + 58816
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4073fec 0x1a4071000 + 12268
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a4076d1c 0x1a4071000 + 23836
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a9611254 0x1a95b7000 + 369236
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a9610f00 0x1a95b7000 + 368384
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001a961146c 0x1a95b7000 + 369772
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a434a108 0x1a429c000 + 712968
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a434a05c 0x1a429c000 + 712796
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a43497c8 0x1a429c000 + 710600
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a4344694 0x1a429c000 + 689812
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a4343f40 0x1a429c000 + 687936
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001ae5d4534 0x1ae5d1000 + 13620
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a84cf580 0x1a7a8c000 + 10761600
20  Ebook Reader                    0x0000000102fa4278 0x102f50000 + 344696
21  libdyld.dylib                   0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000016ceadf20   x5: 0x000000016ceae4d0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000600
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x9e71d097626e80ba  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000069  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001e128ef10  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x0000000103449920  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000103449920
   x24: 0x0000000000005303  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000000016ceaec90  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016ceae430   lr: 0x00000001a40d88b8
    sp: 0x000000016ceae410   pc: 0x00000001a41b8efc cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x102f50000 - 0x10326bfff Ebook Reader arm64  <08564c8a04c532e3ada04acda7479c8b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1AEFE1C6-A710-46C4-ACA8-ECF559C11B29/Ebook Reader.app/Ebook Reader
```

Comment: Have you tested on iPad 13.3.1?

Comment: @RJ168 yes I did

Comment: @matt that so long

Comment: Added comment on my answer below, have a look at it.

Comment: I face the same problem please check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49332660/6479704

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat it's very hard to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can identify the crash problem in better way with symbolicate the log

You get the Symbolicate crash reports from archive that you originally submitted to the App Store

Have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

You also might be using something that is no longer supported by Apple for e.g. `UISearchDisplayController` as mentioned here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126744

If you are using `UISearchDisplayController then you must use`UISearchController`now because starting with iOS 13 and iPad OS 13, UISearchDisplayController is unavailable to apps built with Xcode 11.`

Take a look here
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125520

Comment: I am using UisearchDisplayController, are you sure that cause crash

Comment: @Anna Starting with iOS 13 and iPad OS 13, UISearchDisplayController is unavailable to apps built with Xcode 11. Please have a look at this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125520

Comment: but I don't think it's can crash app

Comment: If you receive one of these crashes but can't reproduce it locally, ensure that you are testing the deployed version of your app on iOS 13, either by using TestFlight, or by applying app thinning to your Xcode archive and testing the thinned variant of your app targeted at iOS 13 devices. By testing with the thinned variant, you will be able to reproduce this crash.

Comment: how to do that! pls test with thinned variant

Comment: actually, UISearchDisplayController cause

Comment: If it is so then you need to use `UISearchController` now.